# Create a listbox with MVVM with links and language in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a listbox that I use to show some items, when you click one you select it and do some actions (like sending you to another page or giving you the option to share it or play it).

I just simply use:

```
<Listbox name:Test>
<ListboxItem name:A>A</ListboxItem>
<ListboxItem name:B>B</ListboxItem>
<ListboxItem name:C>C</ListboxItem>
</Listbox>
```

And in the .cs I define according to the name of the item to reproduce the sound with the same name.

I tried to find how to do it with an MVVM but I couldn't find how, but I need to change the way I do it, since is getting lot of unnecessary code and repeating again and again the same code.

Any idea where can I find a guide to learn about this, and some examples with MVVM using this kind of functions? I can only find how to do a simple MVVM but not making them to do some actions or localized to display the right language according to the country.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVVM => Model View ViewModel

Create your ViewModel

```
     private ObservableCollection<YourObject> _list;
    public ObservableCollection<YourObject> List{
    get{ return _list;}
    set{ return _list = value;RaisePropertyChanged("List");}
}

private yourObjectType _selectedItem;
    public yourObjectType  SelectedItem{
    get{ return _selectedItem;}
    set{ return _selectedItem= value;RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");}
//here your can do anything}
}
```

Your viewModel inherit ViewModelBase.(: ViewModelBase)
And now bind your list to view.

```
<ListBOx itemSource="{Binding List}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem,mode=twoway}" />
```

You can use selectionChangedEvent to in your view. ([Example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/))